# How do I check if there is something in a json file?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

keys.json

```
{
  "__UNUSED": [
    "ABCD",
    "1234",
    "0000"
  ]
}
```

index.js

```
arctic.on('message', async message =>{
  const args = message.content.split(" ")
if(message.content.startsWith("ar!claim")){
const keys = require('./keys.json');
 

   if(args[1] in keys.__UNUSED){
     message.channel.send("Worked.")
     return;
   }else{
     message.channel.send("That is not a key.")
   }

  if(!arctic.commands.get(args[0].slice(3))){
          
    }else{
    arctic.commands.get(args[0].slice(3)).execute(message, args);
  }


}})
```

It keeps on returning "This is not a key" when claiming 1234.
ar!claim 1234 returns "This is not a key".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `in` keyword in javascript checks for 'key', not a 'value'.

use `includes()` method for checking value.

```
if(keys.__UNUSED.includes(args[1])){
  message.channel.send("Worked.")
  return;
} else {
  message.channel.send("That is not a key.")
}
```